# Custom tooltip template in angular syncfusion scheduler

Tags: angular, syncfusion

Got troubles with angular syncfusion scheduler. Does anyone has an idea how to get working custom tooltipe event as per [documentation](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/schedule/appointments/?no-cache=1&_ga=2.122181064.279436534.1589796063-484570459.1583242708#display-tooltip-for-appointments) its noted to add template:

```
<ng-template #eventSettingsTooltipTemplate  let-data>
  <div>My template</div>
</ng-template>
```

and enable tooltip within EventSettingModel `enableTooltip: true` but with this done nothing from the template above appears, am I missing something in this way?

Another way is by providing `tooltipTemplate: '<div>stringtmplate<div/>'` but not nice to have string within a component file instead template, how can I implement it in a proper way?

Comment: Dumb mistake template must be within `ejs-schedule` tags, but hope someone will help this out

Answer (score 0):

We suspect that you have used the Syncfusion Schedule with older version in Angular 9. We recommend you please upgrade the package version to the latest to resolve the problem.

**Latest package version**: **"@syncfusion/ej2-schedule": "18.1.54"**

For more reference, please refer to the below sample.

Sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-urup27?file=app.component.html

Please check the above sample and get back to us for further assistance.